# How to format number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to do dynamic validation on a number while user giving input. Number format should be--  before decimal it should restrict 12 digit and after decimal 2 digit.
I have written one validation function using **Onkeyup** and by giving maxlength. But I am facing issue like, if I remove one digit after decimal then its allowing more than 13 digit before decimal.

below function I have written for validation

```
function validation(e){
    var t = e.value;
    if( t.indexOf(".") <= 0 ) {
        e.value = t.substr(0,12);
    }
    if( ( t.slice( 0, e.selectionStart ).length >= ( t.indexOf(".") + 3 ) ) {
        
        e.value = ( t.indexOf(".") >= 0 ) ? 
            ( t.substr( 0, t.indexOf(".") ) + t.substr( t.indexOf("."), 3 ) ) :
            t
}
```

Appreciate any help!!
Thanks.

Comment: The logic in that function is very convoluted (and it was impossible to read before I reformatted it). I strongly suggest you introduce named intermediate variables (and avoid `slice` as it mutates source data). Also this isn't localizable - have you considered using `Intl` instead?

Comment: Also, if this is for an `<input />` element, have you considered using `pattern=""` instead? That way you don't need any JavaScript at all.

Comment: I would use a regular expression for this. So there can be 1-12 numbers before the decimal point and 0-2 after the decimal point?

Comment: @Dai This is actually xhtml code, I tried using pattern but that is not working as I need to validate on dynamic userInput.Even i tried using convertNumber function as well, but that too not working.

Comment: @michaelT  can you please help me with regex pattern

Comment: Took a few minutes to determine the hopefully correct regex.

Answer (score 1):

### Regex

You can use a regular expression (regex).
For instance:

`^(([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,11}|[0-9]{1}))(\.\d{1,2})?$`

Ok let's check out:

**Numbers before the decimal point:** `([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,11}|[0-9]{1})`
So either `[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,11}` or `[0-9]{1}`, where the first expression prevents leading zeros and second expression makes the input o f `0` possible.

These expressions are followed by an **optional** decimal point `(\.\d{1,2})?`. The `?` means that the expression can be there 0 or 1 times (so the input can be a decimal number or not). After the decimal point there **have to be** one 1 or 2 numbers (decimals).

You can try the expressions here: [Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/).
This should work:

```
123456789123
123.40
0
0.0
953
953.1
953.0
953.01
953.12
```

This should **not** work:

```
1234567891239 // 13 numbers
000.12 // leading zeros
123.001 // Too many decimals
```

### Implementation

Possibility 1 is to insert the regex directly into the `<input>` using the `pattern` attribute. Possibility 2 is to do the validation via javascript. **Note** that you have to escape the backslashes `\\`.

```
let pattern = '^(([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,11}|[0-9]{1}))(\\.\\d{1,2})?$';
let regex = new Regex(pattern);

function validation(e){
    if(regex.test(e.value)){
        // Value fits the pattern
    }else{
        // Value do not fit the pattern
    }
}
```